# JavaFX error, what is sample.fxml

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I've just started with javaFX and I am already beyond confused. When I made this code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FirstFX extends Application{

Label lb_text;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.show();

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().add(lb_text);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    lb_text = new Label("Here's some text");
}

}
```

and It gave me an error that said: Exception in Application start method 
After looking up some fixes a lot of people said something about a "sample.fxml" file and I have no clue what that is or what it is supposed to do. Does anyone know if this is the fix and what I am supposed to do with this sample.fxml file?

Comment: Showing the stage is the last thing you do in the start method, not the first.

Comment: Oh, yes that was it. Thank you.

Comment: Uh, no, that was not it. The issue is that you add a null label to `root` (you call `root.getChildren().add(lb_text)` *before* you initialize `lb_text`. When posting questions involving an error ***always*** include the full stack trace.